# Store data from files in array of structure C

Tags: c

So I'm stuck in this piece of code that I'm writing and I want to save data that I receive from a binary file and save it in a array of structure I already tried something but I can't get any good results.

```
#define MAX_ACCOUNTS 5
#define COUNTER 0
typedef struct t_account {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char provider[40];
    char org[40];
    char domain[50];
    float balance;
} t_account;


    t_account account[MAX_ACCOUNTS];
    char *item;
    FILE *file_accounts;
    char string[0];
    int i = COUNTER;

    file_accounts = fopen("../accounts.dat", "rb");

    if (file_accounts == NULL) {
        printf("Error, %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Testing fread() function: \n\n");
        //fread(string, sizeof(string), MAX_ACCOUNTS, file_accounts );
        while(fgets(string, sizeof(struct t_account), file_accounts )){
            printf("%s\n", string);
            item = strtok(string, ";");

            printf("ID: %i\n", strtol(item,NULL,10));
            item = strtok(NULL, ";");

            printf("Name: %s\n", item);
            item = strtok(NULL, ";");

            printf("Provider: %s\n", item);
            item = strtok(NULL, ";");

            printf("ORG: %s\n", item);
            item = strtok(NULL, ";");

            printf("Domain: %s\n", item);
            item = strtok(NULL, ";");

            printf("Balance: %.2f Eur\n", strtof(item, NULL));
            i++;
        }
    }


    fclose(ficheiro_contas);
```

I already tried to save the data inside the while loop like this but for each field in the structure

```
account[i].id = atoi(item);
```

but the program crashes in the line that I do that piece of code to "save" the array.

Comment: `strtok(string` returns a _pointer into string_. It does not return a _copy_.

Comment: Yes I know, but in that case it returns the first string before the ";" so it I convert it to an integer.

Comment: `char string[0];` is a string of _zero_ length. I certainly is not `sizeof(struct t_account)`. And it does not make sense to read `sizeof(struct t_account)` chars from the file.

Comment: so how would you do it ?

Comment: What about `char string[512];`? And then read the documentation of `fgets`

Comment: but that's not my problem, my problem is storing the result of item into the array "account"

Comment: `strcpy(account[i].name, item);` for example, with `i` the current record.

Comment: If I do that inside the while loop like I said the program will crash in that line...

Comment: Fix the problem of `string` being zero size first and then try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206226/discussion-between-joao-neves-and-paul-ogilvie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your `string` is zero size, yet you try to read `sizeof(struct t_account)` bytes into it. That overwrites other data, causing *undefined behavior* and your crash.

Try:

```
   char string[512];
   int k= 0;
   while(fgets(string, sizeof(string), file_accounts )){
        item = strtok(string, ";");
        strcpy(account[k].name, item);
        //
        // etc...
        //
        k++;
   }
```

Comment: Okay I understand it now, please get in the chat so we can talk better.

Comment: it is now working... finally, how can I add \n inside the .dat file after one string behind ";"?

Comment: like this: "1;Conta1_Amazon\n;AWS\n;IPLeiria\n;ipleiria.pt\n;1213.65;"

Comment: From `gets` documentation: _"The line [gets reads] consists of all characters up to and including the first newline character ('\n'). gets then replaces the newline character with a null character ('\0')"_. But if there are no newline characters int the file, then that's a whole different problem.

Comment: it only saves in the first position of the array

Comment: For any other problem you have, use a debugger to step through the program and check the values of variables etc. My support ends here.